# установить значение счетчика через замыкание

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Вот код счетчика

```
function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;

    function counter(value) {
        return count++;
    }
    return counter;
 }

  let counter = makeCounter();

  alert( counter() ); // 0
  alert( counter() ); // 1
```

Мне нужно сделать возможность устанавливать значение count (как пример -  вызываю ее пару раз и count = 2, потом устанавливаю ему значение 15, вызываю еще раз и функция возвращает 16) установить значение счетчика, но только через замыкание.

Вот мое  нерабочие решение добавить функцию, но как ее вызвать и указать чтобы она изменила значение не пойму)

```
function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;

    function counter() {
        return count++;
    }

    function value (value) {
        return count = value;
    }

    return counter;
}

    let counter = makeCounter();

  alert( counter() ); // 0
  alert( counter() ); // 1
```

Или же была мысль создать внутри переменную value и передать  параметром в функцию counter, а там использовать условие, если есть параметр, то count = value; иначе count++;

И так же по идее должно работать уменьшение счетчика

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  function counter(value) {
    if (arguments.length == 0)
      return count++;
    else
      count = value;
  }
  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();

console.log(counter()); // 0
console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter(15)); // undefined
console.log(counter()); // 15
console.log(counter()); // 16
```

Comment: Я бы только value проверял, а не arguments.length, а так зачет

Answer (score 1):

Лучше аргументами не менять ход выполнения функции. Функция в js - это всё тот же объект, которому можно завести поле с ещё одной функцией, замыкающей `count`.

```
function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;
    function counter()  {
        return ++count;
    }
    counter.reset = function (value = 0) {
        count = value;
        return count;
    }

    return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();

counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2
counter.reset(10); // 10
counter(); // 11
```